# 0-1 knapsack brute force

Tags: c, brute-force, knapsack-problem

I can't seem to find the problem I have with the following code I wrote from a pseudo-code. The function receives array `p[]` with benefits, array `w[]` with weight, `Weight - max weight`, `size (number of items)` and `val (to be returned)`. Please help! Thank you. I think the issue might with the dynamic array or the loops.

```
int bruteforce(int p[], int w[], int size, int Weight, int val){

int k, i, j, tempWeight, tempValue; 
int *A = (int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < pow(2, size); i++)
    j = size;
    tempWeight = 0;
    tempValue = 0;
    while (A[j] != 0 && j > 0) {
        A[j] = 0;
    j = j - 1;
    }
    A[j] = 1;
    for (k = 0; k < size;k++)
    if (A[k] = 1)
        tempWeight = tempWeight + w[k];
    tempValue = tempValue + p[k];
    if ((tempValue>val) && (tempWeight <= Weight))
        val = tempValue;
    return val;
}
```

Comment: You have a logical error or a compilation error?

Comment: Assume a knapsack of two items. How many times each statement of the function should be executed? Use your debugger or insert `printf` in strategic places. After you fix that, what values should `A` assume in each iteration? Use your debugger or insert `printf` in strategic places.

Comment: Thank you! I was having logical errors which turns out to be bad coding.

Answer (score 4):

Ugh! Many things going on here:

- Please indent your code properly. You will then see that you are missing curly braces in two places: The `for` block extends until just before `return val`. The two assignments to `tempWeight` and `tempValue` should also happen inside one block that belongs to the `if` statement.
- The condition `A[k] = 1` is not what you want. It is an assignment that (unfortunately)  also acts as a condition that is always true. Change this to `if (A[k] == 1)`. Some people make a habit of placing the constants first like this: `if (1 == A[k])` which will give a compiler error if you mistype `=` for `==`.
- If you allocate memory for `A`, you must also `free` it before returning from the function.
- Your calculation of the `A[i]` is wrong. Here you have braces, which means that `j` will only be updated if A[j] id not zero. You should implement a binary addition with a carry here.
- The `pow` function is useful for floating-point numbers. Here, you are dealing with integers. It might be better to use `1 << i` instead of `pow(2, i)`. You can also use the carry of the last digit in `A[i]` as a termination criterion; see below.
- This is a minor stylistic point, but once you have braces around the main loop, you'll see that most of your local variables are only needed inside the loop. You should tighten your scope by declaring these variables inside the code block. (This is not important here, but can add to readability in larger programs.)

So, putting all this into your code gives:

```
int bruteforce(int p[], int w[], int size, int Weight, int val)
{
    int *A = (int *) calloc(size, sizeof(int));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; ; i++) {
        int j = size;
        int tempWeight = 0;
        int tempValue = 0;
        int k;

        k = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            A[j] += k;

            k = A[j] / 2;
            A[j] = A[j] % 2;
        }
        if (k) break;

        for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            if (A[k] == 1) {
                tempWeight = tempWeight + w[k];
                tempValue = tempValue + p[k];
            }
        }

        if (tempValue > val && tempWeight <= Weight) {
            val = tempValue;
        }
    }

    free(A);
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Oh My God! This is my first posting here after pulling my hair on that code. Guess I am pretty slow-headed. I can't thank you enough for pointing out all the issues. I instantly learned a lot Mr. M Oehm!